# How to set a click handler for all the elements in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of elements, and I want to set a click handler for all of them, and then do something based on which one was clicked. For the example you can just have it give an alert stating the class of the button that was clicked. My elements look like this: `<input type="button" class="numpad np-txtTP">` and they are all contained in the same element. In my case I want to take whatever is after `np-txt` and add it to a textbox.

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var elements = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements(i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(this.className);
    });
}
```

will assign a click handler to all input elements within an element of id `container` that will alert their classname

---

This can also easily be done in jQuery in the following way if you have access to it

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
        alert($(this).prop('class'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("yourdiv").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "INPUT") {
        //do something to e.target here
    }
}
```

This is called event delegation, and allows you to bind a handler only once for several descendants of an element.